# Почему команда delete в тг боте с базой данных sql не работает

Tags: python, sql, telegram-bot, sqlite, telebot

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['delete'])
def delete_task(message):
    con = sq.connect('organizerbot.sql')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("""SELECT task FROM tasks""")
    task_list = cur.fetchall()
    values = message.text.split()
    con.commit()
    cur.close()
    con.close()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Введите задачу которую хотите удалить.(Список ваших задачей: {task_list})")
    if values in task_list:
        con = sq.connect('organizerbot.sql')
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("""SELECT task FROM tasks""")
        task_list = cur.fetchall()
        values = message.text.split()
        con.commit()
        cur.close()
        con.close()
        con = sq.connect('organizerbot.sql')
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("DELETE FROM tasks WHERE task=?", (values,))
        con.commit()
        cur.close()
        con.close()
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Задача успешно удалена. (Список ваших задач: {task_list})")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Указанная задача не найдена")
```

Comment: Подозреваю, что values это не одно значение, а список. для условия `where task = ?` значение должно быть 1. К примеру `where task = 55`.

Answer (score 0):

Можно через [executemany()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany):

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['delete'])
def delete_task(message):
    con = sq.connect('organizerbot.sql')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT task FROM tasks")
    task_list = cur.fetchall()
    values = message.text.split()
    con.commit()
    cur.close()
    con.close()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Введите задачу которую хотите удалить.(Список ваших задачей: {task_list})")
    if values in task_list:
        con = sq.connect('organizerbot.sql')
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT task FROM tasks")
        task_list = cur.fetchall()
        values = message.text.split()
        con.commit()
        cur.close()
        con.close()
        con = sq.connect('organizerbot.sql')
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.executemany("DELETE FROM tasks WHERE task = ?", map(lambda v: (v,), values))
        con.commit()
        cur.close()
        con.close()
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Задача успешно удалена. (Список ваших задач: {task_list})")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Указанная задача не найдена")
```

Comment: а в чём причина, что оригинальный код не работает??? это неполный ответ. Да, обходное решение вы предоставили, но надо ещё объяснить, почему исходный код не работает. Это как если бы всё за меня делали, я бы ничему не научился.